# Does docker verify images? If so, how is it implemented?

Tags: docker

To me, one of the requirements for putting docker into production use would be the ability to verify that any images we use as base images are in fact the official "ubuntu" or "busybox" images.  I'm not seeing any obvious evidence that images on the public repository are cryptographically signed so that it may be verified that they haven't been tampered with.  Am I missing something?

(As an alternative, I suppose it would be possible to start from scratch with our own base images in our own private registry, but even then I'd want to put some checks in place that we don't accidentally pull anything from the public repo.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker does do "Digital Signature Verification" [as of release 1.3](https://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/), although it is still in very early stages. This verification ensures that any official image you download has not been tampered with in transit. At the time of writing, some official images need to do more work with regards to ensuring files downloaded during the image *building process* are properly checked against stored hashes.

You may also want to look at this [post on container provenance](http://container-solutions.com/2014/10/docker-container-provenance/).

Comment: I don't think "Digital Signature Verification"accomplishes that task.  I've been researching this on my own, and from what I'm reading in the code, Docker generates the hashes on a push and never checks the images again.  The DSV you mention is "Docker Content Trust" which just signs binaries, it doesn't protect against alteration.  Research began here:  https://titanous.com/posts/docker-insecurity#fn:0

Answer (score 2):

Currently, apparently no useful validation is done.

As Adrian Mouat says, [docker 1.3](https://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/) added "something" to do with image verification.

However, findings in [this post](https://titanous.com/posts/docker-insecurity) indicate that only the manifest rather than the image itself is currently verified. That is, the manifest is signed and checked, but the checksum it contains for the image doesn't appear to be used correctly to check the image itself hasn't been tampered with. It is worrying that the apparently broken checksum verification slipped through to a release.

Comment: To be fair, Docker did call DSV a "Tech Preview" and intended it as a point of discussion rather than a solution. It was a bit misleading of them to print "This image has been verified" it large letters though.

Comment: I should have read this answer before posting a comment,  That same site has had me doing a deep dive on the "pull" and "run" commands, and from what I can see based on the baseline I pulled as of last week, Docker generates image sigs on push and never touches the images again.  I haven't tested yet to see if altering images causes error messages, that comes next.

Answer (score 1):

The Docker image verification before 2023 would include:

```bash
 [ Docker Image ] ---> [ Docker Content Trust (DCT) ]
                        |
                        |--> [ Notary Service ]
                        |        |
                        |        |--> [ Signing ]
                        |        |--> [ Verification ]
                        |
                        |--> [ SBOM (Software Bill of Materials) ]
                             |
                             |--> [ Image Metadata ]
                             |--> [ Security Compliance ]
```

It involves:

- **[Docker Content Trust (DCT)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/)**, which uses [Notary](https://github.com/notaryproject/notary), an open-source project, to manage trust over the content. DCT allows operations with a remote Docker registry to enforce client-side signing and verification of image tags.

  Set the environment variable `DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1`. That forces the Docker engine to only use signed images. When pushing an image to a repository, Docker signs the image using the publisher's private key. During image pull, Docker verifies the signature using the publisher's public key.
- **[Software Bill of Materials (SBOM) attestation](https://docs.docker.com/build/attestations/sbom/)**: a detailed record of all components, dependencies, and metadata in a software package, including Docker images. It provides transparency into the composition of Docker images, aiding in vulnerability management, license compliance, and supply chain security.

Both mechanisms, combined, provide a robust framework for verifying and trusting Docker images in production environments.

The DCT part can be backed by [Sigstore](https://www.sigstore.dev/):

```bash
+-------------+       +------------+       +-------------+
|             |       |            |       |             |
|  Docker     +------->  Docker    +------->  Sigstore   |
|  Image      |       |  Content   |       |  (Identity  |
|             |       |  Trust     |       |  Provider & |
+----+--------+       +----+-------+       +------+------+
     |                     |                    |
     |                     |                    |
     +---------------------+--------------------+
     |                     |                    |
     |                     |                    |
     |                 Signature                |
     |----------------------------------------->|
     |                     |                    |
     |                     |                Certificate
     |                     |<-------------------|
     |                     |                    |
     |                     |                    |
     |                     |                    |
+----+--------+       +----+-------+       +------+------+
|             |       |            |       |             |
|  Verify     +<------+  Verify    +<------+  Verify     |
|  Image      |       |  Signature |       |  Identity   |
|  (Client)   |       |  (Client)  |       |  Token      |
+-------------+       +------------+       +-------------+
```

DCT Validates the integrity and publisher of Docker images using digital signatures.
The process begins with Docker Image signing using DCT, where signatures are generated and attached to the image.
SBOM provides detailed information about the components, dependencies, and libraries in a Docker image, contributing to transparency and security assessment.

**Sigstore Verification** involves:

- **Identity Token**: A user logs into their identity provider (e.g., Google, GitHub) and receives an identity token.
- **Fulcio**: The token is handed to [Fulcio](https://github.com/sigstore/fulcio) (part of Sigstore), which issues a signed x509 code signing certificate.
- **Signature and Certificate**: The user signs their code or artifacts using this certificate, which is attached alongside the signature.
- **Verification Process**: A client verifies the code signing certificate (signed by Fulcio), checks the identity and issuer, and validates the signature against the artifact.

---

But: In Oct. 2023, you now have "[Signing Docker Official Images Using OpenPubkey](https://www.docker.com/blog/signing-docker-official-images-using-openpubkey/)", a new strategy for signing [Docker Official Images](https://docs.docker.com/trusted-content/official-images/) (DOI) using [**OpenPubkey**](https://github.com/openpubkey/openpubkey), a project developed jointly by [BastionZero](https://www.bastionzero.com/) and Docker and recently open-sourced to the [Linux Foundation](https://www.linuxfoundation.org/press/announcing-openpubkey-project).

The process involves creating a public/private key pair. The private key remains secret, while the public key is shared publicly. Images are signed using the private key and the image digest, with the resulting signature verifiable by anyone holding the public key.

```bash
+----------------+          +----------------+           +---------------+
|                |          |                |           |               |
|  Docker Image  |          |  Private Key   |           |  Public Key   |
|                |          |                |           |               |
+-------+--------+          +-------+--------+           +-------+-------+
        |                             |                           |
        |                             |                           |
        |       Image Digest          |                           |
        +---------------------------->|                           |
        |                             |                           |
        |                             |                           |
        |          Signature          |                           |
        |<----------------------------+                           |
        |                             |                           |
        |                             |                           |
        |                             |                           |
+-------+--------+          +--------+-------+           +-------+-------+
|                |          |                |           |               |
|  Sign Image    +---------->  Create PK     |           |  Verify Image |
|  (Docker CLI)  |          |  Token using   +----------->  Signature    |
|                |          |  OIDC ID Token |           |  (Docker CLI) |
+----------------+          +----------------+           +---------------+
```

Certificates, which include the public key and an identity name, are used to establish the ownership of a key pair. These certificates are typically signed by a Certificate Authority (CA).
To determine which entities are authorized to sign an image, Docker uses a trust policy, a form of signed metadata. The Update Framework (TUF) is utilized for securely updating this policy.

To handle certificate expiry issues, Docker employs a Timestamp Authority (TSA), which bundles a timestamp with the signature, allowing verification that the certificate was valid at the time of signing.
Transparency logs (TL) are used to store signatures and certificates, providing a mechanism to detect misuse or compromise. Signatures and certificates are only valid if accompanied by a TL receipt.

The OpenPubkey Protocol binds OIDC (OpenID Connect) identities to public keys. It involves the creation of a PK token, a new kind of token that validates both the OIDC identity and the control of the private key.
OpenPubkey has been enhanced to address potential issues like OIDC ID tokens being bearer auth tokens and the risk of key compromise. Solutions include using Guillou-Quisquater (GQ) signatures and including the image hash in the nonce to prevent token replay.

So far, [the reactions](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=37786781) are not exactly positive:

> As far as I can tell, you're relying on Google, or Microsoft, etc to verify your identity. Lose your relationship with them, and you lose control of everything. You have to remain in their good graces, or lose your identity for a diverse set of transactions where those big players would otherwise have no sway.
>
> Would much rather have a truly decentralized identity where you can change providers without losing continuity of your identity. Where your identity provider has to keep you happy, or you transparently move your identity to a new provider.

And:

> This seems very poorly thought through. Everything from abusing the nonce as a data channel (and re-using a predictable value in a field that is short for Number used Once), to rejection of transparency for an inherently public value, misunderstanding the threat models here, and putting the responsibility for revocation on to the client (one of the most complicated things to do correctly in a potentially already compromised environment...).
>
> I think this one needs to go back to the drawing board.

So let's wait if this new strategy will be adopted. The [Sigstore-based approach](https://blog.sigstore.dev/openpubkey-and-sigstore/) seems more robust.